# Checking View Controllers' tab bar member is my view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to check whether specified index of view controllers in a tab bar is my view controller?

I have done below code:

```
if(((UIViewController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]) == BookmarkViewController)
```

But it gives error:

> Unexpected interface name 'BookmarkViewController': expected
>   expression

What is the correct way to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert it in following valid line of code :

```
if([[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] isKindOfClass:[BookmarkViewController class]])
```